# Spring JUnit testing, Failed to Load ApplicationContext, error creating beans

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I'm attempting to write some unit tests for my data access object, but I'm running into a little trouble where I can't seem to load the `ApplicationContext`.

Here's my stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext.dataSource(ApplicationContext.java:53)
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8023e4f0.CGLIB$dataSource$2(<generated>)
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8023e4f0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fdcd37a6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8023e4f0.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 43 more
DEBUG                 [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] {2015-12-08 13:45:39,644}-> Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@10b48321: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,applicationContext,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration,viewControllerHandlerMapping,mvcContentNegotiationManager,mvcResourceUrlProvider,resourceHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerMapping,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcUriComponentsContributor,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,mvcValidator,mvcPathMatcher,mvcUrlPathHelper,mvcViewResolver,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionAttributeSource,transactionInterceptor,viewResolver,env,dataSource,jdbcTemplate,mailSender,transactionManager,emailDAO,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator]; root of factory hierarchy
ERROR                 [org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager              ] {2015-12-08 13:45:39,644}-> Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5f2108b5] to prepare test instance [com.blah.stagedemailmanager.dao.EmailDAOTest@676cf48]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext.dataSource(ApplicationContext.java:53)
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8023e4f0.CGLIB$dataSource$2(<generated>)
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8023e4f0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fdcd37a6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8023e4f0.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 43 more
DEBUG                 [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener] {2015-12-08 13:45:39,656}-> After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@10cf09e8 testClass = EmailDAOTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3327bd23 testClass = EmailDAOTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config.ApplicationContext}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.web.WebDelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Here is my `EmailDAOTest`:

```
package com.blah.stagedemailmanager.dao;

import blah;..

@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class EmailDAOTest
{
   @Autowired private EmailDAO emailDAO;

   @Test
   @Rollback(true)
   public void testStage()
   {
      StagedEmail email = (StagedEmail) new StagedEmail().setType(EmailType.TEST).setFrom("test@blah.com")
                  .setRecipients(new Recipient().setType(RecipientType.TO).setAddress("recipient@blah.com")).setSubject("subject").setText("text");

      long id = emailDAO.stage(email, 74492);
      assertEquals(emailDAO.getEmail(id), email);
   }
}
```

And here's the `ApplicationContext`:

```
package com.blah.stagedemailmanager.config;

import blah;..

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
   @Override
   public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer)
   {
      configurer.enable();
   }

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
   {
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      return viewResolver;
   }

   @Bean
   Environment env()
   {
      return Environment.determineCurrentTomcatEnvironment();
   }

   @Bean
   DataSource dataSource()
   {
      BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
      ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      ds.setUsername("USERNAME");
      ds.setPassword("PASSWORD");
      ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@" + env().getDatabaseName());
      ds.setMaxActive(10);
      ds.setMinIdle(1);
      ds.setMaxIdle(5);
      ds.setTestOnBorrow(true);
      ds.setValidationQuery("SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL");
      ds.setInitialSize(1);
      ds.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
      ds.setMaxWait(90000);
      return ds;
   }

   @Bean
   NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate()
   {
      return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager()
   {
      return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   JavaMailSender mailSender()
   {
      JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
      mailSender.setHost("exchange.blah.com");
      return mailSender;
   }

   @Bean
   EmailDAO emailDAO()
   {
      return new EmailDAO(jdbcTemplate());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You threw a NullPointerException in the dataSource() method in your ApplicationContext class (line 53 to be exact), but since you didn't include the code for that method, so its hard to help any further.

Comment: Sorry. I just edited the question to include the definition of dataSource().

Comment: i suspect env() is returning null which means Environment.determineCurrentTomcatEnvironment() is returning null.  I suggest you set a breakpoint in the dataSource() method and step thru that code.

Comment: You are correct, `Environment.determineCurrentTomcatEnvironment()` is returning `null`. I'll poke around and see what I can do with it. Will report back with updates. Thanks!